# DocuSign get envelope documents returns empty

Tags: docusignapi

I'm having an issue retrieving the document list. I have a simple function below which is using the EnvelopesApi to simply get a list of EnvelopeDocument by referencing the envelopeID. When I call this function, the list "documents" has a size of 0. When I check the envelope object, the envelopeDocuments is also showing a size of 0.

When I check through the DocuSign sandbox account however, the envelope being referenced does indeed have one document. So I don't understand why it's returning a size of 0.

Any idea what might be the issue?

```
public Map<String, String> getProviderDocuments(String packageId) {
        Map<String, String> documentFields = new HashMap<>();
        EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient);
        Envelope envelope;

        try {
            envelope = envelopesApi.getEnvelope(docuSignAdapterHelper.getDocuSignAccountId(), packageId);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("ERROR: Failed to get envelope.", ex);
            throw new ESignatureException("Failed to get envelope.", ex);
        }

        List<com.docusign.esign.model.EnvelopeDocument> documents = envelope.getEnvelopeDocuments();

        for (EnvelopeDocument doc : documents) {
            log.info("DocuSignAdapter document name: " + doc.getName());
            log.info("DocuSignAdapter document file id: " + doc.getDocumentId());
            documentFields.put(doc.getName(), doc.getDocumentId());
        }

        return documentFields;
    }
```

[Image of envelope object in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtNRp.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a `ListDocuments()` call to get the list of documents and all related information about documents.

https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/list/

Comment: Thanks! I really gotta read the API manual a bit more next time...